# how to free memory in C that was allocated using C++ "new" operator

Tags: c++, c, malloc, free, new-operator

I make my own C/C++ libraries with some functions written in C; other in C++. Inside the library I use the `new` operator:

```
mystruct * mystruct_alloc()
    {
    mystruct * ms = new mystruct;
    return ms;
    }
```

Now I use this library in C like this:

```
mystruct *ms = mystruct_alloc();
// do stuff
free(ms);
```

When I check this with valgrind; I get warnings like this:

```
Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
```

But I have the impression that all memory is freed correctly. I know that there are two ways to circumvent this problem.

***I could rewrite my C++ code to use malloc:***

```
mystruct * mystruct_alloc()
    {
    mystruct * ms = (mystruct *) malloc (sizeof(mystruct));
    return ms;
    }
```

***I could write a `dealloc` function in my library:***

```
void mystruct_dealloc(mystruct *ms)
    {
    delete ms;
    }
```

and I would have no more problems; but what is the best way? `new` is easier to use; but it gives those warnings in valgrind. So here are **my questions:**

1. Is all memory freed correctly if I use `new` and `free`? (so the valgrind warning is not very important)
2. Is there a preferred way to program this?

Comment: To answer the question in the title: You don't. If you need to allocate memory and pass it to C code and let it free the memory, then you must use `malloc`. There is nothing that specifies that the `new` operator have to allocate from the same pool as `malloc`, or even behave similarly in other ways.

Comment: C: `malloc` and `free` | C++: `new` and `delete`. You should not mix it.

Comment: properly design your interface, like adding `mystruct_free(mystruct *)` to make a pair.

Comment: I notice there is update in the question, so I would add, mixing `new` & `free` is undefined behaviour. It's OK to use `malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete` pair if `mystruct` is POD.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It is not guaranteed to be freed correctly, but it *might*, depending on the compiler and runtime library.
2. You *always* should return memory in the corresponding way to how you got it:

   - `free` for `malloc`
   - raw `delete` for raw `new`
   - a user defined `operator delete` for a user defined `operator new`
   - if your storage was provided by some DLL, return it to that DLL for proper deallocation
   - if you cut open a dinosaur's belly to get your storage, return the memory into the same dinosaur's belly and close it again with a few stitches.

In your case, write and call a corresponding function in your C++ library:

```
void mystruct_free(mystruct* ms)
{
  delete ms;
}
```

Comment: ..and the added benefit that any other allocation/deallocation scheme, (eg. struct/object pools), could be added later without changing the interface.

Answer (score 4):

Other than just avoiding the mixed up `new` with `free`, you must also ensure that de-allocation is being done by same heap-manager, same runtime library. For example, if you `new` or `malloc`, with **X** version of a runtime library (which manages memory and heap), you cannot `delete` or `free` using **Y** version of runtime library (Yes, even if `new` is matching `delete`).

That's the reason, it is recommended that allocation made by a DLL (Windows), should be de-allocated by same DLL. Since other DLL may have another heap-manager/runtime-library. It is also advised to free memory by same thread.

Answer (score 3):

1. No it's not freed correctly. Never mix `malloc/free` and `new/delete`.
2. You already know the solution. Either use `malloc`, or write `dealloc` function. I would prefer the latter as it would be more consistent with the construction.

Answer (score 1):

Returning pointers from C to C++ and vice-versa could create problems for you. Since there would be a chance to mix up `malloc/delete` OR `new/free` which would result in an un-defined behavior. OR you have to take care of that explicitly that it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

1) Never use new and free combination . I have tough time debugging one issue :(

2)Better write a small code which mimics the malloc and free operation. I hope you are not using memory allocation extensively

Answer (score -1):

If you allocate with `new`, you must deallocate with `delete`.

If you provide a function to allocate your object, the user of your function does not need to know if your object is allocated with `new`, `malloc`, `mmap`, `return BIG_ARRAY + (index++)`, `obstack_alloc`, `my_custom_allocator.allocate(sizeof(mystruct))` or any other way: you have to give a deallocation function.

The deallocation function must be paired with the allocation function (and use the deallocation method matching the allocation method used in the allocation function).

This way, the user does not have to know how your object has been allocated and if you change the way you allocate your object at some other point in time, it won't break the caller code.

Comment: I guess you wanted to write something else. `new` and `free` do *not* match. *"... if your object is allocated with free..."* -> You could not possibly allocate an object with `free`

Comment: Indeed, I mixed my keywords/functions while I was typing :)